# Calculate $\int_{\left| z \right| = 1} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z-2} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem is finding the value of

$$
\int_{\left| z \right| = 1} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z-2} dz
$$

My idea is to use the residue theorem. The function has 2 singularities, which are $z = 0$ (essential) and $z = 2$ (pole), since 2 is outside of the unit disk I only care about the singularity at $0$.

So I need to find the residue at $0$, my idea was to use the geometric series to get a series for $\frac{1}{z-2}$, it only converges for $\left|z\right|< \frac{1}{2}$ but I could just integrate there instead since the value would be the same residue (please let me know if this is wrong) and then multiply by $exp(1/z)$

I got $\frac{1}{z-2} = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^n}$ and $e^{\frac{1}{z}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{-n}}{n!}$.

Next I multiply the series to get the residue, and got $-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n! 2^{n-1}}$, I might have messed up the computations but even if not, this seems really ugly and doesn't actually answer the question, the series I got is convergent but that's it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%281%2Fz%29%2F%28z-2%29 gives the Laurent series.

Comment: Also this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laurent+series+e%5E%281%2Fz%29%2F%28z-2%29+at+z%3D0

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!2^{n-1}}=2(e^{1/2}-1)$$

Comment: The wolfram link shows the series I wrote, geometric series times exp(1/z), I don't see how that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series you got is $1-\sqrt e$ so $\oint_{\left| z \right| = 1} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z-2} dz=2\pi i (1-\sqrt e)$ but a more elegant to do it is to go to infinity since $e^{\frac{1}{z}}=1+O(1/z), |z| >R$ large.

So using the residue theorem (the residue at $2$ being trivially $\sqrt e$) $\oint_{\left| z \right| =1} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z-2} dz+2\pi i\sqrt e=\oint_{\left| z \right| = R} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z-2} dz, R >2$

As noted $\oint_{\left| z \right| = R} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z-2} dz=\oint_{\left| z \right| = R} \frac{1+O(1/z)}{z-2} dz=i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{Re^{it}+O(1)}{Re^{it}-2}dt \to 2\pi i$ as $R \to \infty$ hence $I=2\pi i (1-\sqrt e)$ directly without doing the Laurent series!

Comment: You should change most of your $\int$s  to $\oint$s (`\oint`).

Comment: I assume that's a classic method but it seems very nice to me.

Comment: It is part of the integral computations with residue toolkit - very useful for rational functions too